# Shemona Veshiv'im Umeya - mi yodeya?

Tags: mi-yodeya-series, number

### Who knows one hundred seventy-eight?

*Please cite/link your sources, if possible. At some point at least twenty-four hours from now, I will:*

- *Upvote all interesting answers.*
- *Accept the best answer.*
- *Go on to the next number.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

178 chapters in אבן העזר‎.

Answer (score 2):

At the sixth zionist congress, 178 people voted against (and 295 for, with 99 abstentions) sending an exploratory expedition to Uganda.